# Translating literal object into object's properties

Tags: javascript

Given this object:

```
var myObject = {name: 'David', date: '11/13/2014'};
```

I want my constructor to set its object properties based on *myObject*:

```
function myClass(_object){
    // set given object's properties here
}
```

I want to set the properties through a loop, so I wont have to set every property by hand - because the object will be dynamic.

I'm looking for a cross-browser solution.

Comment: `this.name = _object.name || "Joe";`

Comment: Oh, what's your question?

Comment: @Jonathan this is very obvious, I'm sorry I didn't mention but the object may be dynamic, so I won't set every property. I want some sort of loop to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you want is this:

```
function MyClass(_object) {
  for (var p in _object) {
    if (_object.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      this[p] = _object[p];
    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget to use `new`:

```
var obj = new MyClass(myObject);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/v40o5duf/1/)**